# Expected unqualified-id cstdlib

Tags: javascript, c++, ios, objective-c, spidermonkey

I integrated SpiderMonkey Library in my Objective C Test Project.In main.mm(I renamed it to .mm for C++) I imported file

```
#include "jsapi.h"
```

When Compiling I see two errors.

Expected unqualified-id cstdlib

Expected unqualified-id new.

See image of compile time errors I am getting

[image]

Adding Another Image for further reference.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the error message as text? There's no usable information in that picture

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot This is the Error no further associated description.I have added another picture of error if that can help you somewhat.

Comment: I can't copy paste text from pictures. Also, that's not the compiler output, but a screenshot of the code where the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Importing `#include <iostream>` in the file did the trick for me.